# let f be analytic in $Ball_2\left(0\right)$ and f is odd. let $U=\left\{z\in \mathbb{C}|1<\left|z\right|<2\right\}$, prove equality

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, even-and-odd-functions

Sorry for title being not full, could not write it all:
let f be analytic in $Ball_2\left(0\right)$ and f is odd.
let $U=\left\{z\in \mathbb{C}|1<\left|z\right|<2\right\}$
Prove:
$\exists f\in Analytic\left(U\right):\:\forall z\in U,\:s.t:\:z\left[1-z^2\right]F'\left(z\right)=f\left(z\right)$

My problem in this is with the solution of the professor.
He assumed I can use the given value of the proof, what I mean is:
he said that we have the $\left[1-z^2\right]F'\left(z\right)=f\left(z\right)$ as given, switch sides of the equation, then do integral on $F'(z)$, use residue theorem and reach zero ( it is easy to prove it ).
My problem with the proof is, he is using what I have to prove as given, he does not show a way to reach the equation $\left[1-z^2\right]F'\left(z\right)=f\left(z\right)$
Is the solution of the proffesor right? is it true that I can always use the data given in what I have to proof? it just does not seems right to me.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Laurent series of $f.$ The even terms are zero. You can divide by $z$ and obtain the series with only even terms. Then you multiply by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}$ , obtaining the series with even terms. Finally you take the antiderivative. The main point is that $z^{-1}$ does not show in the last series.

Comment: yea, I reached it myself, I did exactly as you said, problem is that it wont help me. I managed to prove that way that the integral of a closed loop of $f(z)$ is actually 0, but I cant manage to get the equation part

Comment: the problem part here is not to show it has anti-deriavtive, the problem is how do I get the equation part without using it as a given value? or there is not a way? and if so, why is it allowed to do so? is it not wrong in terms of discrete math?

Comment: The function ${f(z)\over z(1-z^2)}$ is holomorphic in $1<|z|<2$ and is even. Hence ${f(z)\over z(1-z^2)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^{2n}.$ Then $F(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{a_n\over 2n+1}z^{2n+1}$. By the way it suffices that $f$ is analytic in $1<|z|<2.$

Comment: I guess then I have to use the equation that I want to prove as given? :\
I guess there is no other choice. Thanks though :) 
Thought there is a way of reaching it alone, without the proof

Comment: There is a misprint in your post $\exists F.$ I did use  the equation.

Comment: Oh My god, you are right, I did not notice it, I checked it 4 times and it wasnt like that before, really sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation  $$z(1-z^2)f'(z)=f(z)$$ has no nontrivial odd solutions holomorphic in $|z|<2.$ According to my calculations if $$f(z)=\sum a_n z^{2n+1}$$ then $$a_n=a4^{-n}{2n\choose n}$$ Hence the radius of convergence is equal $1.$

However I suspect that the original task was: for a given odd function $f,$ find $F$ satisfying the equation $$z(1-z^2)F'(z)=f(z)$$ The solution is presented in my comment.

Comment: oh dam you are right, really sorry!! and thank you very much for sticking to me althought I did to you problems!